# How to scrape element with BeautifulSoup out of a table?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to extract the content of the right side on this page:

https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=idn%3D1173921214

[image]

When we take a look on the html, the information is stored in this table:
[image]

With my code snippet, I can´t reach the text I want to.

```
def getDescriptionDNB():
    description = f'https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=9783125466302'
    response = requests.get(description)
    soupedDescription = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    text = soupedDescription.find(class_="amount").text
    if text == "Treffer 1 von 1":
        autor = soupedDescription.find_all("tr")
        for i in autor:
            test = i.findNext("td").text
            print(test)
```

The problem is, I don´t know how to get down to the inner `<td>` tag to get the information I want to.

Do you know, how I can solve this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Main issue is - HTML of page is broken, there are some `tr` without `td` and without closing tag.*

Try to select your elements more specific or try to store info in `dict` and pick by key.

Create a `dict` with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
...
dict(
    row.get_text(':',strip=True).split(':',1) 
    for row in soup.select('tr:has(td:not([colspan]))')
)
```

Create a `dict` with [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd
url = f'https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=9783125466302'
pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna().set_index(0)[1].to_dict()
```

###### Output

Based on url of your snippet.

```
{'Link zu diesem Datensatz': 'https://d-nb.info/94985462X',
 'Titel': 'Learning English - Password red:Teil: Reformierte Rechtschreibung / 3. / [Hauptw.].',
 'Ausgabe': '1. Aufl., 1. Dr.',
 'Verlag': 'Stuttgart ; Düsseldorf ; Leipzig : Klett',
 'Zeitliche Einordnung': 'Erscheinungsdatum: 1997',
 'Umfang/Format': '172 S. ; 25 cm',
 'ISBN/Einband/Preis': '978-3-12-546630-2 Pp. : DM 29.60:3-12-546630-X Pp. : DM 29.60:3-12-54663-0 (falsch) Pp. : DM 29.60',
 'Sprache(n)': 'Englisch (eng), Deutsch (ger)',
 'Frankfurt': 'Signatur: 1997 A 10551:Bereitstellung  in Frankfurt',
 'Leipzig': 'Signatur: 1997 A 10551:Bereitstellung  in Leipzig'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break apart the key/value pairs as pointed out. Sticking with BeautifulSoup (your tool of choice) -

```
        teilen = i.find_all('td')
        if len(teilen)==2:
              print(teilen[0].text.strip(), ' : ', teilen[1].text.strip())
```

There are some other things. Improve on this yourself. Instead if selecting all the 'tr's in the document select the table, and then select the table:

```
table id="fullRecordTable"
```

and then move on to selecting the rows ('tr') in there.